# opening QComboBox triggers mouseMoveEvent but not mousePressEvent

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, mouseevent, qcombobox

in my code I have two comboboxes inside and I intentionally designed a frameless borderless window; so I had to define mouse events manually to move window on click and drag, and resizing on edges.
without comboboxes it works perfectly, but somehow clicking on combos to open them trigger only mouseMoveEvent and not mousePressEvent, causing an error about there is no self.old_Pos. if we uncomment last three lines of **init** function, this error is gone, but on openning combos whole window will be displaced. how can I overcome this problem?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.combo1 = QComboBox()
        for i in range (0,10):
            self.combo1.addItem('Combo1 label %s' %str(i))
        self.combo2 = QComboBox()
        for i in range (0,15):
            self.combo2.addItem('Combo1 label %s' %str(i))
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo1)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo2)
        # design title bar
        title_bar = QHBoxLayout()
        title_bar.setObjectName('HeaderBar')
        title_bar.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        title = QLabel('title bar')
        btn_size = 35
        btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size,btn_size)
        btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        btn_min = QPushButton("_")
        btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        title_bar.addWidget(title)
        title_bar.addWidget(btn_min)
        title_bar.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        title_bar.addWidget(btn_close)
        main_layout.addLayout(title_bar)
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        #self.old_Pos = QPoint(0,0)
        #self.old_width = self.width()
        #self.old_height = self.height()
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()
        self.old_width = self.width()
        self.old_height = self.height()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.old_Pos)
        if (self.old_Pos.x() > self.x() + self.old_width - 10) or (self.old_Pos.y() > self.y() + self.old_height - 10):
            self.setFixedSize(self.old_width + delta.x(),self.old_height + delta.y())
        else:
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()
    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        quit()
    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            self.btn_max.setText('+')
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.btn_max.setText('R')
    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.showMinimized()        
app = QApplication([])
mainapp = MainWindow()
mainapp.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you describe. Everything works the same and gives no errors.

Comment: @S.Nick, let me show it to you with a gif: https://gifyu.com/image/EVcQ.
I know that the problem is in line 46 shown in gif. But my question beside off course how to solve this problem, is why opening combobox trigger mouseMoveEvent but not mousePressEvent.

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei What version of PyQt5? I think it was a bug that could only be seen in Windows, and in the other OSs it was not observed (for example in PyQt5 5.13 in Linux I do not observe what you point out), I also remember that another user asked the same and could solve it , I recommend you do a search in SO.

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei I think this is the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54991

Comment: `Windows 7`, `PyQt5 5.12.1` - everything works correctly.

Comment: @S.Nick maybe it's a specific version of PyQt5 that has that bug. As indicated previously, another user pointed out the same bug, but I could not find that question

Comment: dear @S.Nick,and eyllanesc here is the versions I use: PyQt5: 5.12.2, python: 3.7.4, pyinstaller: 3.5, windows 7 64 bit. I am still running this script in my machine and result is what I have described above. the reason I don't use pyqt 5,13 is that after using pyinstaller to make exe file, it won't run and gives error (I think) about not finding  _struct function.

Comment: I used a frameless borderless window, and everything works fine. the problem arises when I am trying to override mouseEvents to make the window draggable and resizeable. I just tried to know how many times function mouseMoveEvent has been called on opening comboboxes, and each time it gave me a number greater than 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I solved this problem.
all we have to do is to define `self.old_Pos = None` inside `__init__` and `mouseReleaseEvent`, and put an `if self.old_Pos:` statement inside mouseMoveEvent.
here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.combo1 = QComboBox()
        for i in range (0,10):
            self.combo1.addItem('Combo1 label %s' %str(i))
        self.combo2 = QComboBox()
        for i in range (0,15):
            self.combo2.addItem('Combo2 label %s' %str(i))
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo1)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo2)
        # design title bar
        title_bar = QHBoxLayout()
        title_bar.setObjectName('HeaderBar')
        title_bar.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        title = QLabel('title bar')
        btn_size = 35
        btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size,btn_size)
        btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        btn_min = QPushButton("_")
        btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        title_bar.addWidget(title)
        title_bar.addWidget(btn_min)
        title_bar.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        title_bar.addWidget(btn_close)
        main_layout.addLayout(title_bar)
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.work_with_combo = True
        self.old_Pos = None
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()
        self.old_width = self.width()
        self.old_height = self.height()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.old_Pos:
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.old_Pos)
            if (self.old_Pos.x() > self.x() + self.old_width - 10) or (self.old_Pos.y() > self.y() + self.old_height - 10):
                self.setFixedSize(self.old_width + delta.x(),self.old_height + delta.y())
            else:
                self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
                self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.old_Pos = None
    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        quit()
    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            self.btn_max.setText('+')
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.btn_max.setText('R')
    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.showMinimized()        
app = QApplication([])
mainapp = MainWindow()
mainapp.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for this solution **FOREVER**.  Just wanted to thank you so much for posting the solution.  Worked perfectly for me!

For anyone using just Qt Creator, here is the ultimate code I used:

```
//Declare oldPos in .h private
QPoint oldPos = QPoint();

void GiftCardDialog::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    oldPos = event->globalPos();
}

void GiftCardDialog::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    (void)event;
    oldPos = QPoint();
}

void GiftCardDialog::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    if(!oldPos.isNull()) {
        QPoint delta = event->globalPos() - oldPos;
        if(oldPos.x() > this->x() + this->width() - 10
                || oldPos.y() > this->y() + this->height() - 10) {

        } else {
            move(this->x() + delta.x(), this->y() + delta.y());
            oldPos = event->globalPos();
        }
    }
}
```